# Locally convex implies convex?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

There is a question about convex set.

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be an open, connected set. If for any $x\in\overline{\Omega}$, there is a neighborhood $U_x$ such that $\Omega\cap U_x$ is convex, then $\Omega$ is convex.

Intuitively, if $\Omega$ is not convex, there must be a point on $\partial\Omega$ such that $\Omega$ is not convex locally. But I have no idea how to write it clearly. Thanks to your help.

Comment: Some geometrically obvious facts with convex sets can be difficult to prove.

Comment: Simple pictures will show that this is false even in the plane. All open sets in $\Bbb R^n$ are locally convex. But many open sets are not convex, even though they are connected.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, but points on the boundary must also satisfy the $\Omega \cap U_x$ being convex property. An example does not pop out at me.

Comment: Isn't an annulus a counterexample or am I missing something?

Comment: @Thorgott Look at the inner boundary circle.

Comment: Ah, thanks.$\ \ $

Comment: The answer must involve connectivity in some way.

Answer (score 4):

Let $B_r(x) \subset \mathbb R^n$ denote the open ball with center $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and radius $r > 0$. For $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $t \in  \mathbb R$ define $L(x,y;t) = (1-t)x + ty$ and $L(x,y) = \{ L(x,y;t) \mid  t \in [0,1] \}$ = line segment from $x$ to $y$.

A *polygonal chain* in $\mathbb  R^n$ is a set of the form
$$P(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} L(x_i,x_{i+1})$$
The $x_i$ are called its *vertices*. We also say that $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is *polygonal chain from $x_1$ to $x_n$*.

Lemma 1. If $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open and connected, then for any two $x,y \in \Omega$ there exists a polygonal chain $P \subset \Omega$ from $x$ to $y$.

Proof. Let $x \in \Omega$ and let $U$ be the set of points $y \in \Omega$ which admit a polygonal chain $P \subset \Omega$ from $x$ to $y$. Then $U$ is open: Let $y \in U$ and $P(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \subset \Omega$ be a polygonal chain from $x$ to $y$. We have $B_r(y) \subset \Omega$ for some $r > 0$, thus for each $y' \in B_r(y)$ the set $P(x_1,\ldots, x_n,y') \subset \Omega$ is a polygonal chain from $x$ to $y'$. Also the complement $V = \Omega \setminus U$ is open: For $y \in V$ we have $B_r(y) \subset \Omega$ for some $r > 0$, and if $y' \in U$ for some $y' \in B_r(y)$, then there is a polygonal chain $P(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \subset \Omega$ from $x$ to $y'$, hence $P(x_1,\ldots, x_n,y) \subset \Omega$ is a polygonal chain from $x$ to $y$, a contradiction. The connectivity of $\Omega$ shows that $U = \Omega$.

Lemma 2. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be *regular* (which means that it is open, connected and satisfies the local convexity property of the question) and let $P(x,y,z) \subset \Omega$ be a polygonal chain with three vertices. Then also line segment $L(x,z)$ is contained in $\Omega$.

Proof. Assume that $L(x,z)$ intersects the closed set $C = \mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega$. In particular it is impossible that  $y \in L$ and we conclude that $x, y, z$ lie in a (unique) two-dimensional affine plane $E \subset \mathbb R^n$.
For $t \in [0,1]$ let $T(x, t) \subset E$ denote the solid triangle with vertices $x, y, y_t =  L(y,z;t)$. For $t = 0$ it is degenerate to the line segment $L(x,y)$. The line segment $L(x,y_t)$ is an edge of $T(x,t)$ and we have $T(x,t) = \bigcup_{s \in [0,t]} L(x,y_s)$. Define
$$A = \{ t \in [0,1] \mid T(x, t) \subset \Omega \} , \tau = \sup A .$$
We have $0 \in A$, thus $\tau \in [0,1]$. We claim that $A$ is open in $[0,1]$. Let $t \in A$. Then $[0,t] \subset A$ since $T(x,s) \subset T(x,t)$ for $0 \le s \le t$. The line segment $L(x,y_t)$ has positive distance $d > 0$ from $C$. For suffienctly small $\epsilon > 0$ we see that for all $s \in (t - \epsilon, t + \epsilon)$ each point in $L(x,y_s)$ has distance $< d/2$ from $L(x,y_t)$. Hence $L(x,y_s)$ has positive distance from $C$ for $s \in (t - \epsilon, t + \epsilon)$ which implies that $L(x, y_s) \subset \Omega$ for $s \in (t - \epsilon, t + \epsilon)$. We conclude that $T(x,t') =  \bigcup_{s \in [0,t']} L(x,y_s) \subset \Omega$ for $t' \in [0,1] \cap (t - \epsilon,t + \epsilon)$.

By definition $[0,\tau) \subset A \subset [0,\tau]$. We claim that $\tau \notin A$, i.e. $A = [0,\tau)$. If $\tau = 1$ this is clear since $1 \notin A$ and follows from the fact that $A$ is open if $\tau < 1$.

This means that $\tau$ has the property $T'(x,\tau) =  T(x,\tau) \setminus L(x,y_\tau) \subset \Omega$ and $C_\tau = L(x,y_\tau) \cap C \ne \emptyset$. Therefore $C_\tau \subset \overline \Omega$, but $C_\tau \cap \Omega = \emptyset$. Now define
$$\sigma = \inf\{ s \in [0,1] \mid L(x,y_\tau;s) \in C_\tau\} .$$
Clearly $0 < \sigma < 1$ and $\xi = L(x,y_\tau;\sigma)$ is the point on $L(x,y_\tau) \cap C \subset \overline \Omega$ which has the smallest distance to $x$. Let $U$ be an  open neigborhood of $\xi$ such that $U' = U \cap \Omega$ is convex. There exists $\sigma' \in (0,\sigma)$ such that $\xi'  = L(x,y_\tau;\sigma') \in U'$. We find $r > 0$ such that $B_r(\xi') \subset U'$. The set $B_r(\xi')$ contains a point $\xi'' \in E \setminus T(x,\tau)$. We have $\xi'' \in U'$. The ray which starts at $\xi''$ and goes through $\xi$ contains a point $\eta \in T'(x,\tau) \cap U'$. Since $U'$ is convex, we get $\xi \in L(\xi'',\eta) \subset U' \subset \Omega$, a contradiction since $\xi \in C_r \subset C = \mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega$.

Corollary: Each regular $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is convex.

Proof: Let $x,y \in \Omega$. Let $P(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \subset \Omega$ be a polygonal chain from $x$ to $y$ with $n$ *minimal*. Assume $n > 2$. Then Lemma 2 gives us a polygonal chain in $\Omega$ from $x$ to $y$ with $n-1$ vertices, a contradiction. Thus $n =2$, i.e. $L(x,y) \subset \Omega$.

Comment: Thank you! That’s a very nice answer.

Comment: It would be really nice to have an illustration of the proof

Answer (score 3):

I will follow the proof of the theorem from the [answer in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/661188/574443). The accepted answer in the aforementioned post is much cleaner but relies on some ideas from abstract functional analysis to generalize the result to arbitrary topological vector spaces, which personally I find thoroughly depressing. The proof I present is more on the concrete, hard analysis side.

It suffices to show the result for bounded $\Omega$, since convex sets are closed under taking ascending chains (just intersect $\Omega$ with open balls of increasing radii). By the [Lebesgue covering lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma), there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $x \in \overline\Omega$, there exists $y \in \overline\Omega$ such that $B_\epsilon (x) \subseteq U_y$, so in particular $B_\epsilon (x) \cap \Omega$ is convex. In other words, $\Omega$ is *uniformly* locally convex.

Recall open connected implies path connected and $\overline{\Omega \cap U_x}$ is convex, so $\overline \Omega$ is path connected ([this is not true in general!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286896/is-the-closure-of-path-connected-set-path-connected)). The path length function, given by
$$\text{length}(\gamma) = \sup_{\Pi} \sum_{i} |\gamma(t_i) - \gamma(t_{i + 1})|$$
where the supremum is taken over partitions $\Pi$ of whatever the domain of a continuous path $\gamma: [a, b] \to \overline \Omega$, is lower semicontinuous as the supremum of continuous functions.

Fix $x, y \in \overline\Omega$, then arguing by Arzela-Ascoli and arclength parametrization (cf. [for example this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097985/closure-of-a-region-and-shortest-path)), there exists a path $\gamma : [0, 1] \to \overline\Omega$ of minimum length between $x$ and $y$. We claim that $\gamma$ is a straight line, which would prove convexity of $\overline\Omega$ and therefore its interior $\Omega$.

By uniform continuity, we can find $n \in \mathbb N$ sufficiently large such that
$$ |\gamma(i/2^n) - \gamma((i + 1)/2^n)| < \epsilon $$
for all $i = 0, \dots, 2^n - 1$. For brevity, denote $a_i = \gamma(i/2^n)$. We have $a_i \in \overline\Omega$ and $a_{i - 1} , a_{i + 1} \in B_\epsilon (a_i)$. Since $\overline \Omega \cap B_\epsilon (a_i)$ is convex (follow the usual proof of showing convex sets are closed under closure), there exists a line between $a_{i - 1}, a_{i + 1}$ in $\overline \Omega \cap B_\epsilon (a_i)$, call it $\Gamma_i$. But then we can parametrize
$$ \gamma([0, (i - 1)/2^n]) \cup \Gamma_i \cup \gamma([(i + 1)/2^n, 1]) $$
as a path from $x$ to $y$ in $\overline\Omega$ which has length
$$ \text{length} \ \gamma([0, (i - 1)/2^n]) + |a_{i + 1} - a_{i - 1}| + \text{length} \ \gamma([(i + 1)/2^n, 1]) \geq \text{length} (\gamma). $$
Rearranging,
$$ |a_{i + 1} - a_{i - 1}| \geq \text{length} \ \gamma([(i - 1)/2^n, (i + 1)/2^n]). $$
But of course, straight lines are the unique shortest paths in Euclidean space, so this implies the section of the path $\gamma([(i - 1)/2^n, (i + 1)/2^n])$ is straight. Arguing for each $i$ tells us $\gamma$ is in fact a straight line, completing the proof.

**Edit (minor technicality):** it is not entirely obvious that a rectifiable (i.e. finite length) path exists between any two points, but this follows from the uniform continuity + local convexity argument from the final part of the proof, which for arbitrary paths allows us to construct piecewise linear (often called "polygonal") paths in $\overline\Omega$ between two points, which clearly has finite length. The existence of this construction is often times convenient to use in complex analysis, and of course in this scenario.

Comment: It will take me a while to grind through, but very nice approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and it will take me a while to comprehend this answer.