# Intersection of an unbounded domain and annulus around a boundary point (with controlled radius) is a domain

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness, path-connected

Is it true that given any unbounded domain $D$ strictly in $\mathbb C$ and a boundary point $z_0$, and two real numbers $R > r > 0$, I can choose some $r' < r$ and $R' > R$ such that $\{ z \in D : r' < |z - z_0| < R'\}$ is a domain?

Here an open subset of $\mathbb C$ is called a domain if any two points in the subset can be joined by gluing straight broken line segments in the subset.

Comment: $z_0$ doesn't appear anywhere, did you perhaps mean $r'<|z-z_0|<R'$?

Comment: @Ic2r43 Thanks! Yes, I meant that.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is the step of the exercise I am trying to solve now (about maximum principle) and I am stuck on this part. I tried drawing some example to find some counter example, but haven't found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let
$$D = \mathbb C \setminus \{ z = x + iy \mid x \in \{0\} \cup \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}, y \ge 0 \} .$$
Then $z_0 = 0$ is a boundary point of $D$. Now let $A$ be any annulus around $0$. Then $A \cap D$ has infinitely many connected components.

Comment: I am not sure if $D$ is a domain here.

Comment: @TrashFailure In fact **each** open and connected subset is a domain in your sense. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3960180. In the present case it is even simpler: Each point of $D$ can be connected by a vertical line segment with the line $L = \{x+iy \mid y = -1\}$.