# Gluing lemma for convex functions?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $A, B$ are two open intervals of real numbers such that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset.$ Suppose there are two convex functions $f: A\to\mathbb{R},$ and $g: B\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in A\cap B.$ Then the function $$ F(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x\in A\setminus B$} \\
g(x), & \text{if $x\in B$}
\end{cases}$$ ought to be convex. If both $f, g$ are differentiable (or twice differentiable) the proof is straightforward. I suppose a proof without this assumption can be given via [the three slopes rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140679/how-to-prove-that-convex-function-has-an-increasing-slope) but did not succeed yet.
Can somebody give a proof or a reference for this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is true for open intervals $A, B$ because [convexity is a local property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4642999/42969) for functions defined on open intervals.

Every $x \in A \cup B$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $\left.F\right|_U =\left.f\right|_U$   or $\left.F\right|_U =\left.g\right|_U$, so $F$ is locally convex and therefore convex.